# Is this function of class $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, both or none?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I have the following function:

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x^{3/2}}$$

To prove it is $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, one has to prove this integral converges:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{|\sin(x)|}{|x|^{3/2}}\, dx$$

and to prove it is $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, one has to prove this integral converges:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin^{2}(x)}{x^{3}}\, dx$$

Could someone please help me solve these integrals?

Comment: you dont need to solve them to prove if they converge or diverge, find some majorant or minorant for each integrand, or divide the intral in sums and estimate the value of each sum

Answer (score 0):

Change the domain of integration to just $[0, \infty)$ for the first integral, which we can do since the integrand is even. Write $\int_0^\infty = \int_0^1+ \int_1^\infty$. On $[0, 1]$, $|\sin(x)|\le x \implies |\sin(x)|/x^{3/2}\le 1/\sqrt{x}$, whose integral converges on this domain. For $[1,\infty)$, $|\sin(x)|/x^{3/2}\le 1/x^{3/2}$, whose integral also converges on this different set.

For the second one, the first part of the same argument fails, though the second one does work.